# DataView in AMPScript

Tags: dataview, exacttarget, ampscript

Is it possible to access SendLog and DataView data i.e. _Click via AMPScript to populate email content? Something like:

```
%%[SET EmailContent = _Click(linkName);]%%
```

I know how to run SQL query and save this as a Data Extension but I'd like to use it on the fly. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using one of the AMPScript lookup functions.  Here's a simple example:

```
%%[
var @DEColumn1, @lookupValue
set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @DEColumn1 = Lookup("DataExtensionName", "ReturnColumn", "LookupColumn", @lookupValue)

]%%
DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%
```

I have a few more examples of the different lookup types are [here](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/) on my blog.

UPDATE: Example retrieving _Click data:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "aspriggs@degdigital.com"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("_Click",@numRowsToReturn,"EventDate desc","SubscriberKey", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @jobID, @batchID
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @jobID= field(@row,"jobID")
set @batchID= field(@row,"batchID")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, jobID: %%=v(@jobID)=%%, batchID: %%=v(@batchID)=%%<br>

%%[

next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Reference: [System data views](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

Comment: Thanks Adam but it isn't exactly what I expected to hear. Or you answered half of my question. 


I know how to use lookup when data is in ET, but how do you access _Click or _Send data in Salesforce without running sequel? I have just checked SendLog and this is not there

Comment: The system data view data is in ET and you can treat it just like any other data extension.  I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Brilliant. This helps a lot. I will teak this for to my requirements. 

Amazing, thanks for your input Adam!